# matplotlib graph line not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
def sortlist():
     list1 = [x for x in range(0, 1001)]
        random.shuffle(list1)
        start = perf_counter()
        list1.sort()
        end = perf_counter()
        plt.plot(len(list1), (end - start))
        plt.show()
```

This code doesn't show the line on the graph for some reason.

Comment: provide list in `plot()`. It is not showing because you are giving plot values as contants.

Comment: Sorry I'm proper stuck. I've tried removing len and just using list1 but I get a valueError saying the dimensions must match.

Comment: This is because `(end-start)` is also constant and also size of the plot value, not matches.

Comment: Try `plt.scatter(len(list1), (end - start))` to show a dot, as you only have one x,y value.